# Magic The Gathering: keyword for power at least X

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I would like to know if there is a keyword that basically means 'if the creature has a power of at least X'. A friend told me there might be, but I couldn't find it. I wouldn't be surprised if I missed it, so I'd like to know if anyone here has heard of it.

Comment: Are you thinking of [Ferocious](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=+[ferocious]||type=+[ferocious]||subtype=+[ferocious]||text=+[ferocious])? It's not a keyword, and checks whether you have *a* creature with power at least 4, rather than a specific creature and a variable threshold, but it's similar and a pretty recent mechanic.

Comment: What kind of "keyword" are you looking for? Are you searching for creatures with at least X power on Gatherer, or looking for an ability word? Like Jefromi said, Temur brought with it Ferocious and its cousin Formidable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no such keyword ability, and no other word used in that specific context. Whenever a card has an effect that depends on the power of the creature, it's usually phrased as an English sentence, i.e. "Creatures with power less than Aura Gnarlid's power can't block it." on [Aura Gnarlid](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=271147)

It's hard to link to something that doesn't exist, but neither the list of [Keyword Actions](https://rules.wizards.com/rulebook.aspx?game=Magic&category=Game%20Rules#3181) nor [Keyword Abilities](https://rules.wizards.com/rulebook.aspx?game=Magic&category=Game%20Rules#3182) in the Comprehensive Rules mentions anything of the sort.